# ¿Caul es la sintaxis para definir restricciones de clave foranea en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Lo que en SQL SERVER es

```
constraint fk_name
     foreign key references tabla(campo)
```

Comment: Así mismo funciona en MySQL

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp Ej: PersonID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me gustaria agregar esto a mi propia pregunta, a mi me funciono la siguiente sintaxis:
Estamos construyendo la tabla 'EQUIPO', cuya clave primaria es 'ID_EQUIPO' y esta relacionada con la tabla 'TORNEO', como puedes ver tambien especificamos la clave foranea 'ID_TORNEO' y se muestra la forma de especificar la relacion y que pasara en el ON DELETE y ON UPDATE

```
CREATE TABLE `EQUIPO`( 
`ID_EQUIPO` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`NOMBRE_EQUIPO` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
`GENERO_EQUIPO` BIT NOT NULL,
`ID_SECCION` INT NOT NULL,
`ID_TORNEO` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID_EQUIPO`),
FOREIGN KEY (`ID_TORNEO`) REFERENCES `TORNEO`(`ID_TORNEO`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE 
);
```

Tambien se muestra como designar como primary key a un campo.
Espero que os sirva!

Answer (score 0):

Se declara

```
CONSTRAINT fk_tabla1_tabla2 FOREIGN KEY(columnaFK) 
REFERENCES tablaDestino(PKtabla);
```

**ACLARACIONES**

- `fk_tabla1_tabla2` será el espacio donde colocarás el nombre designado para este `CONSTRAINT` y poder identificarla
- `FOREIGN KEY(columnaFK)` es la función que recibe el nombre de la llave foránea que declaramos y que nos servirá para vincular  con la llave primaria de la otra tabla
- `tablaDestino` es el nombre de la tabla que tiene la llave primaria, donde por dentro de los paréntesis le pasamos el nombre de la llave primaria de la tabla principal

**ACOTACIONES PARA EL CONSTRAINT**

1. `CASCADE`: Los valores que estén directamente vinculados, por las llaves primarias y foráneas se eliminarán
2. `RESTRICT`: Impedirá la acción solicitada
3. `SET NULL` Los valores que están directamente vinculados con la llave que se trata de eliminar y/o actualizarán se establecerán a `NULL`
4. `NO ACTION`: Muy parecido a `RESTRICT` impedirá la acción solicitada

Lo anterior para indicar que pase con los valores anteriores

Comment: De verdad agradezco tu respuesta, sin embargo yo use otra sintaxis, no sé si es que hay varias o que pasa, pero a mi me funcione la siguiente sintaxis (Abajo en la respuesta)